# How do i find the ip address of a server in a homegroup

Tags: network-programming, client-server, ip-address, static-ip-address

I have a number of devices connected to a server. When it restarts the ip address might change. How would the remaining devices find the new address?

I want to automate the process since I want to distribute the software and there won't be any network administrator.

I found solutions like configuring a DHCP server or manually configuring the router, but it won't possible to manually configure the routers of the devices that would use the software.

Comment: You should use statically assigned or DHCP reserved IP addresses for things like servers, printers, etc.

Comment: the client devices are actually windows or ios based systems

Comment: Right, but if you make sure that the server is always at the same IP address, it doesn't matter what the clients are, or how they get their addresses assigned.

Comment: Ya but the problem is i can't configure every device that uses this software to be manually configured.

Comment: You basically have two choices: the clients can connect to the server via IP address or DNS (which translates server names into IP addresses). Somehow, you need to configure a client to tell the client one or the other, or the user of the client will need to do this. It really depends on the application. A web site doesn't configure every client to connect to it, the user must enter a DNS name or an IP address in order to connect to the web server. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is following :-

1. Assign static IP-Address to the server; it could be done by adding a reservation for server's IP-Address based on the MAC address of the server in the router. Check your router manual for how to add IP-Address reservation for a designated MAC-Address.
2. Once server has got a static IP-Address, your work would be so easy to achieve. You either need to ensure that the clients make an entry of the server's hostname and the corresponding static IP into the client's host name OR if you've an adhoc connection(WiFi/Bluetooth), it would do that automatically without your intervention.

That's it, you have a static IP-Address for your server and you have mapping of server's IP-Address and hostname into each client's `etc/hosts` file(not needed for adhoc connections as explained above).

Comment: How do I do this programmatically?

Comment: @JibinMathew - IS this the way to ask question on SO? No programming language tag, nothing! At least add this in your question. Now coming to your query, you could easily map the static server IP to the hosts file of every client and call them in Java, using `InetAddress.getByName("SERVER-HOSTNAME");` It'd work flawlesssly, give it a try.

Comment: @JibinMathew - Also, if the answer helped/helps, please accept and upvote the answer. Good Luck and feel free to ask your doubt.

Comment: The answer that you gave seems like a manually configuring the router, please give a programmatic approach in setting up the servername @Am_I_Helpful

Comment: @JibinMathew - Setting up a servername can be done easily in clients by editing hosts file in each client; but, you need to have a reserved IP_Address for server in the router table. That is done the same way even in companies. If you want that too programmatically, you can check for your router's API access, and hard code to reserve an IP for server --- I ain't sure whether this is done. There is no problem in reserving an IP for server in the router; rest all processes can be automated and be done using Java.